# Return all users that have one or more published blog posts

Tags: users

I am working on a plugin for which I need to create an array of all users (name and ID) that have one or more publish blog posts.

Looking at the documentation for `get_users()` it does not seem to have an arg value for this particular requirement.

How do I obtain this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an argument for this, and it is documented. If you look at [the documentation for `get_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) is says this:

> See [WP_User_Query::prepare_query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_User_Query/prepare_query/). for more information on accepted arguments.

If you follow that link you'll see the list of arguments, and one of those is:

> **'has_published_posts'**
>
> *(bool|array)* Pass an array of post types to filter results to users who have published posts in those post types. `true` is an alias for all public post types.

So you can get published authors like this:

```
$authors = get_users( [ 'has_published_posts' => true ] );
```

Or, if you just want users who have published posts:

```
$authors = get_users(
    [
        'has_published_posts' => [ 'post' ],
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set "orderby" and "who" in get_users:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

```
   $usersList = get_users( 'orderby=post_count&who=authors' );
      foreach ( $usersList as $user ) {
      echo '<li>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</li>';
  }
```

Comment: I know it had to be possible. Thank you.

Comment: And you can use count_user_posts($user->ID) in this foreach loop to remove users without any post.

Comment: Setting the `who` argument to `authors` limits the result to users based on their user level. It has nothing to do with whether or not the user has any posts.

Answer (score -2):

You can always use custom sql queries to perform things like that.

```
function custom_query(){
    global $wpdb;
    $tbl_users = $wpdb->prefix . "users";
    $tbl_posts = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";

    $sql = "SELECT ID, user_nicename FROM $tbl_users where ID in (SELECT post_author from tbl_posts WHERE post_status='publish' group by post_author);";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if($results){
        foreach($results as $row){
            response[] = array($row->ID, $row->user_nicename);
        }
        return response;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have tested the sql command. But didn't test the complete PHP implementation. But I think you got the idea.

**EDIT:** I have add this method just to show that you could always go for custom queries if you stuck on something.

Comment: Using SQL is always a fallback. I was hoping for a pre-existing method.